# Recursively Traverse Binary Tree

Tags: binary-tree

This is probably a simple task for expert coders, but is it possible to recursively traverse a binary unordered tree to find a node?

I can do this for a binary search tree, but I'm struggling with how to do this when the tree is unoredered since I can't figure out how to traverse back up when a node is not found in a branch...

C++ would he helpful.

Thanks guys.

Comment: why do you have an unbalanced/unordered tree? surely the point of a binary tree is for really fast searches.

Comment: What have you done so far? Do you have any code you can show us to show what you tried?

Answer (score 1):

use iteration. pseudo code below:

```
ITERATIVE-TREE-SEARCH(x, k)
 while x ≠ NIL and k ≠ key[x]
     do if k < key[x]
           then x ← left[x]
        else x ← right[x]
 return x
```